# Allocating block of memory then creating logical sub blocks of memory and returning pointers to those sub blocks

Tags: c, pointers, memory, memory-management

I got asked this question on an interview and I'm pretty confused after trying to google/search on SO:

*"Write a C function that allocates 4K block of memory, then creates 10 logical sub-blocks and returns pointer to each of the sub-block"*

I'm not entirely sure what "logical sub-block" means in the question. What's the best way to approach this?

Can I simply allocate a 4k block using malloc, and then creating additional pointers incremented by the 1/10 of the size (4k)? Is there some smart bit-manipulation tricks that make this easy?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, You are asked to allocate 4k block of memory and split it into sub blocks by dividing the allocated space equally into 10 logical blocks and return a pointer to the first byte of each block.

Comment: You wouldn't be able to do any bit manipulation to divide the blocks I guess.

Answer (score 2):

"Can I simply allocate a 4k block using malloc, and then creating additional pointers incremented by the 1/10 of the size (4k)? Is there some smart bit-manipulation tricks that make this easy?"

I think that it's not about bit-manipulation tricks, because dividing 4k by 10 is fairly easy.

What I'd be much more concerned about is the fact that `malloc` will give you a pointer that is suitably aligned for any data type (cf, for example, this [online C standard draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) ):

> 7.22.3 Memory management functions
>
> (1) The order and contiguity of storage allocated by successive calls
>   to the aligned_alloc, calloc, malloc, and realloc functions is
>   unspecified. **The pointer returned if the allocation succeeds is
>   suitably aligned so that it may be assigned to a pointer to any type
>   of object with a fundamental alignment requirement** and then used to
>   access such an object or an array of such objects in the space
>   allocated (until the space is explicitly deallocated).

Yet dividing such a memory block by 10 and picking out pointers to these chunks may likely give you pointers that are not properly aligned for the data types which you want to store then therein.

Comment: The same standard does say that all alignments are powers of two, and that the fundamental alignment, which e.g. `malloc()` provides, is `_Alignof (max_align_t)` (which evaluates to a power of two of type `size_t`). If `max_align` is that value, then `max_align * (size_t)(4096 / (max_align * 10))` is the size (or offset in `char`s) of each subregion. (Unfortunately, I'm not exactly sure how widely the C11-specific `_Alignof (max_align_t)` is supported in currently used C compilers.)